# Oracle Datadiff

Tags: oracle

(Oracle) I have to return all records from last 12 months. How to do that in PL/SQL?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to explain, I do have a column of DATA type

Answer (score 3):

Doing this in PL/SQL is pretty much synonymous with doing it in SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-12)
```

You might like to fiddle around with the TRUNC statement to get exactly the range you want -- I used TRUNC(SYSDATE) which is the same as TRUNC(SYSDATE,'D') -- ie. remove the time portion of the sysdate. For example, if it is currently Aug 12 but you want values from Feb 01 instead of Feb 12 then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12)
```

Also, see the docs for treatment of months having different numbers of days: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  date_column > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
```

Not sure I deserved down-modding for the earlier posts... was only trying to help.

Comment: There's no such function as ROLL_MONTHS in Oracle

Comment: Just because you were trying to help doesn't mean the answer was right. I'm sure most people here are only trying to help. Don't be offended by mod downs, learn from them.

Comment: Matthew... I was objecting to the fact that he'd neglected to mention that he had a DATE column (see the later edit above)... I had asked if he did have a DATE column (post now deleted) and got down-modded for it.  I felt that was harsh.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  date_column > SYSDATE - 365
```